# How to start sonar analysis against a tag/version of a project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We have a little specialized issue. We have a long-living software product having need of supporting multiple bugfix and hotfix branches for fixing issues on the older released versions of our product. Before reintegration of all branches they have to pass an analysis via eclipse-sonarqube-plugin.

For quality analysis of these branches we want to check against the sonar analysis of the corresponding version of our product. E.g. if we have a bugfix branch corresponding to version 4.4.98 than the analysis should be made against version 4.4.98 and not the current version 5.1.50.

Is there an easier way to do this than creating special sonar product keys for the specified versions or is this possible to be done out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the analysis of each branch must be run. You can use the "sonar.banch" property to not have to "change" the project key. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there was an way to do so without having for each version an aditional branch to analyse changes against.